# Windows explorer - Column that shows the number of lines in text files

Tags: windows, windows-8, text-files, windows-explorer

I have a lot of text files in a folder.
How can I see in the windows explorer (windows 8) a column with the number of lines for each text file?
If I can't, is there any other files explorer that can show this information?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom columns were available only on XP. Starting from Vista such possibility was removed. One of the alternative is Total Commander. TC supports plugin architecture and you can create your own plugin which will show any information you need in additional column.